# WSO2 DataService: How to handle oracle refcursor that returns 'no data found'?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 4.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.8. I have Data Services Server feature enabled(3.2.2)

Working on Data Service (.dbs file) having a  Stored procedure with oracle ref cursors as out parameter. If the Stored procedure returns data, then the data service written is working fine, but when the stored procedure had 'no data found' then the cursor returned is empty and hence the element is not returned and hence the below error.

Could someone give an insight as how to handle this particular scenario on refcursor in WSO2 dataservice?

"[2013-01-11 10:49:02,902] ERROR - SQLQuery DS Fault Message: Error in 'StaticOutputElement.execute', cannot find parameter with type:column name:class
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

DS Fault Message: Error in 'StaticOutputElement.execute', cannot find parameter with type:column name:class
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

```
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.StaticOutputElement.getParamValue(StaticOutputElement.java:201)
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.StaticOutputElement.execute(StaticOutputElement.java:239)
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElementGroup.execute(OutputElementGroup.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.writeResultEntry(Query.java:335)
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery(SQLQuery.java:908)
at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2044)
```

"

Here is the .dbs file that I have written

```
<data  name="dsname">
<config id="datas">
  <property name="carbon_datasource_name">datas</property>
</config>
<query id="procedure_YEAR" useConfig="datas">
  <sql>{callProcdure (?,?,?,?)}</sql>

  <result element="array" rowName="dict" >
  <element name="status" column="out_status" xsdType="xs:string" />
   <element name="error_desc" column="out_error_desc" xsdType="xs:string" />
    <element name="class" column="class" xsdType="xs:string" />
    <element name="org" column="org" xsdType="xs:string" />
    <element name="year" column="year" xsdType="xs:number" />
    <element name="week_yr" column="week_yr" xsdType="xs:number" />
  </result>
  <param name="in_year1" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"  />
  <param name="out_status" sqlType="STRING" type="OUT"  />
  <param name="out_error_desc" sqlType="STRING" type="OUT" />
  <param name="result" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="INOUT" />
<!--  <param name="class" sqlType="STRING" type="INOUT" />
  <param name="org" sqlType="STRING" type="INOUT"  />
  <param name="year" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"  />
  <param name="week_yr" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"  />
  <param name="bill_amount" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"  />
  <param name="bill_unit" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"  />
  <param name="yoy" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"  />-->

 </query>
 <operation name="YEAR_op">
  <call-query href="procedure_YEAR">
     <with-param name="in_year1" query-param="in_year1" />
   </call-query>
 </operation>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

With DSS 3.0.0 and later versions you can set optional="true" for the result elements where value is not certain. So in your case for the elements which are returned from REF_CURSOR set optional="true" in result element definitions of your dbs.

ex:

```
<result element="array" rowName="dict" >
  <element name="status" column="out_status" xsdType="xs:string" />
   <element name="error_desc" column="out_error_desc" xsdType="xs:string" />
    <element name="class" column="class" xsdType="xs:string" optional="true"/>
    <element name="org" column="org" xsdType="xs:string" />
    <element name="year" column="year" xsdType="xs:number" />
    <element name="week_yr" column="week_yr" xsdType="xs:number" />
  </result>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But this answer did not seem to work, it still showed me the same error .<element name="error_desc" column="out_error_desc" xsdType="xs:string" />
        <element name="class" column="class" xsdType="xs:string" optional="true" />
        <element name="org" column="org" xsdType="xs:string" optional="true" />
        <element name="year" column="year" xsdType="xs:number" optional="true"/>
        <element name="week_yr" column="week_yr" xsdType="xs:number" optional="true"/>

It still goes and checks for params compatibility in the result

Comment: This fix was included to Data Service 4.0.2 features.

Comment: Thanks! I need to try with that version of DS then.

Comment: I am using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 with DS 3.2.2 enabled. I could not find the the DS version 4.0.2 as the jar available is 'org.wso2.carbon.core-3.2.3'.
Is the DS version 4.0.2 available as downloadable? 
How do I enable this version of DS in ESB? Will this be available in ESB 4.5.1?

Comment: Yes for ESB 4.5.1, 4.0.2 features are available for installing. http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.2/

Comment: Thanks for replying promptly!

Comment: Hi
For now I cannot user ESB 4.5.1 as I have been using ESB for quite sometime now and need to finish few services.
Tried to enable DS 4.0.2 in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3,(via feature management configuration in WSO2 ESB Management Console, using this url http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.5/) but all it asked for dependencies to be enabled,while doing so.I had tried to include the dependencies asked for , but got stuck with the below one.

Comment: (Cont)..
It was referring to below dependency (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.0.2,4.1.0])which I believe is not there in the even latest 4.0.5 repository. When searched for carbon core via consile, with repositories (4.0.0,4.0.2,4.0.5)only version 4.0.0 was available.
 Could you please tell the order of dependencies?

Comment: cont..(Cont)..
It was referring to below dependency (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.0.2,4.1.0])which I believe is not there in the even latest 4.0.5 repository. When searched for carbon core via consile, with repositories (4.0.0,4.0.2,4.0.5)only version 4.0.0 was available.
 Could you please tell the order of dependencies?
Error Shown:
"Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management Feature 4.0.2 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.feature.group 4.0.2) requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.0.2,4.1.0)' but it could not be found"

Comment: WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 is running on top of carbon 3.2.3. So you cannot install any carbon features of 4.x series. Because they are only compatible with carbon 4. So the only option to use latest features,is upgrading to latest ESB. ESB 4.5.0 and latest versions are compatible with carbon 4.x features.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling perhaps ?                                                     callProcdure = callProcedure